# Best Way to Start database from particular number(id) + rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

Rails app + mysql db. 
I want to start the db on production from a particular id, what is the best way to do it.
The first that is coming to my mind is seeding. Is there any better way I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Mysql2 in a rails app there's a database called 'information_schema' and it has a table called 'tables' and it has a record where the column `table_schema` is the name of your sql database and the column `table_name` is the name of your model's table.  The column `auto_increment` is the next record number to use.

so (for example) for database "my_database" for model table "posts" to set that to start at 500 you would do the following SQL command...

```
UPDATE information_schema.tables SET auto_increment = 500 WHERE table_schema = 'my_database' AND table_name = 'posts';
```

Comment: So, for Production which is ec2 for me, I go on rails console and run this SQL command? Once run will it nor auto-increment always like first record at 500 and second at 1,000 or only once like 500,501?

Comment: It will increment 500, 501, 502, and so on.  You can do it via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE infor...(blahblahblah)...'posts';")` provided you have permission to access the database.